# Level and experience algorithm

Tags: algorithm

Can we get either the level up XP or total XP from a closed formula? If so, what formula?

This is from gambling site i have found and the "Daily" is money you can get every 24hours

Is there any algorithm I can follow to get something like that? Thank you for your ideas
 [image]

Comment: A hardcoded table is also an algorithm. Why do you need anything more?

Comment: I dont think its just a hardcoded table, there might be anything behind what generated the code

Comment: It might be. But why do **_you_** need anything more? How would you use it such that you can't use just a table?

Comment: Draw Level/Daily and Level/upXP charts. They may give you an idea about the (polynomic?) formula used.

Comment: I think that algorithm should make me this table... its easier than to write it down on my own. And i have not idea how should i construct that on my own

Comment: An screen copy with the data is not exploitable. Please provide arrays of values or plots.

Comment: pastebin: [link](https://pastebin.com/UMbFSMSS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Level n total xp = 30 * (n-1)^4

2: 30 * 1^4 = 30
3: 30 * 2^4 = 480
...
40: 30 * 39^4 = 69,403,230
```

Found via prime factorization.

```
$ factor 69403230
  69403230: 2 3 3 3 3 3 5 13 13 13 13
$ factor 62554080
  62554080: 2 2 2 2 2 3 5 19 19 19 19
```